# Strange error when including Graphics.hpp - SFML

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, sfml

I'm trying to setup an SFML 2.1 64 bit project on Ubuntu 12.04(also 64 bit) using eclipse cdt.

- First I made a new project called LearningSFML.
- Then I went to Project>Properties>C/C++ Build>Settings
- Under GCC C++ Compiler>Includes I added the path to my include folder
- And under GCC C++ Linker>Libraries I added `sfml-window`, `sfml-graphics`, `sfml-system`(in that order) to the "Libraries" list
- And finally added < SFML_PATH >/lib to the "Library search path" list box

After doing this, I tested it with the following code

```
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::Window window(sf::VideoMode(640, 480), "Learning SFML");

    return 0;
}
```

And if flashed a window as you would expect. But changing the code slightly to use `sf::RenderWindow` instead of `sf::Window`:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(640, 480), "Learning SFML");

    return 0;
}
```

creates an error saying `make: *** [LearningSFML] Error 1`. I searched the internet for similar problems. One website I found said that the error means there is no main function, but clearly I do have a main function.

So how can I fix this error?

Comment: What is the entire error?

Comment: @RetiredNinja That is all it says. It's under the "Problems" tab on eclipse.

Comment: You should be able to find the full error from the compiler output.

Answer (score 0):

The console was outputting `warning: libjpeg.so.62, needed by lib/libsfml-graphics.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)` which is where I was an idiot because I didn't look at this until RetiredNinja's comment.

To fix it just install libjpeg:
`sudo apt-get install libjpeg62`